# android latitude/longitude formats

Tags: android, location, format, latitude-longitude

I need to make some calculations using the user current lat/long and some values stored in the db.
The problem is that Location.getLatitude() returns a value like 4119778.0 and my values in the db are saved like 41.16753.

I tried to look to the Location.convert functions but i cant find anything.

How can I make the values the same format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your type in database is set to double it should not be a problem.
And Location.getLatitude() returns normaly a value between - 50 to + 50.
Can you give us some code? I never needed to format when i used getLatitude() and store it into database.

Comment: you are right. It was a stupid mistake from myself. I was copy/pasting the default coordinates into the emulator with the wrong decimal separator (. instead of ,). Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

getLatitude() and getLongitude() will return doubles representing the degrees, the fractional part are minutes and seconds represented as decimal fraction.

Make sure to declare the column type as REAL and use getFloat() to read the columns from the cursor after a query.